# Lighting/Shading Issues Not Caused By Normals

Tags: shaders, lighting, normals

I'm in the process of making some low poly characters, and normally it's pretty straightforward but there are some weird things happening with the lighting/shading on this one character (shown below) and I can't figure out why.

My first guess was that it was an issue with the normals, but all of them are facing the correct way. My second guess was that there could be some duplicate vertices somewhere, but that also was not the case.

Is anyone able to tell me why this is happening? I would really appreciate the help. Also please let me know if there's any more information that would be helpful for me to provide.

Thanks!

[image]

Normals:

[image]

Comment: Did you used shade smooth?

Comment: @Emir Yes everything is smooth shaded.

Comment: @Emir Yes, thank you so much!

Comment: this has nothing to do with normals, it has to do with split normals, which are the normals used for the shading, Blender tries to smooth between the faces, have you enabled the Auto-Smooth option in order to only smooth under a certain angle?